# General proof for square–cube law

Tags: geometry

Can someone present a general (and easy) proof for square-cube law?

For similar objects 1 and 2,
$$
\frac{A_1}{A_2}=k^2 \ \mathrm{and} \ \frac{V_1}{V_2}=k^3,
$$
where k is the scale of objects 1 and 2.

Comment: Is it as simple as $(k\Delta x)(k\Delta y) = k^2(\Delta x\;\Delta y)$ and $(k\Delta x)(k\Delta y)(k\Delta z) = k^3(\Delta x\;\Delta y\;\Delta z)$ ?

Comment: What kind of objects are you interested in? Can they be literally any shape?

Comment: The exponents $^2$ and $^3$ are, in some conventions, the definition of two-dimensional and three-dimensional. It is a definition that allows for objects to have non-integer dimensions.

Comment: I am hoping to get a general proof that works for any objects that are similar. So yes, the objects can be any shape.

Comment: I've posted what is hopefully the general proof you want; note basically that it formalizes what @user already said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a cube we have that

- $A_1=l_1^2$
- $V_1=l_1^3$

and

- $A_2=l_2^2$
- $V_2=l_2^3$

then by $k=\frac{l_1}{l_2}$

$$\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\left(\frac{l_1}{l_2}\right)^2=k^2 \ \mathrm{and} \ \frac{V_1}{V_2}=\left(\frac{l_1}{l_2}\right)^3=k^3$$

For a complex boby we can think to divide it in many small cubes and apply the same reasoning to obtain the same result as a limit.

Comment: Can you justify a little more why dividing a complex body into infinitely many small cubes works when calculating the surface area? For example, dividing a cone into many short cylinders (in the limit each just becoming circles) and taking the limit of the combined surface area yields the wrong answer in that case.

Comment: @paulinho My answer was aimed to give an intuition starting from the simple case for the cube.

Comment: If I have two similar objects 1 and 2, such that their scale is k. Does that mean, that one of them is divided into infinitely small cubes with volumes of $$ \mathrm{d}V_1=\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z, $$ and the other is divided into cubes with volumes of $$ \mathrm{d}V_2 =k\mathrm{d}x \cdot k\mathrm{d}y \cdot k\mathrm{d}z = k^3 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}z \ ?$$

Comment: @mathslover Yes exactly that's precisely the idea!

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminaries:**

One way to define similarity of two three-dimensional shapes $X$ and $Y$ would be to say that when you put $X$'s center of mass on the origin of the three-dimensional grid and scale the length of each coordinate axis by some number positive number $k$, you obtain $Y$, but possibly rotated. The scaling can be represented as the linear transformation
$$S = \begin{bmatrix} k & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & k & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & k \end{bmatrix}$$
while the rotation can also be represented as some orthogonal transformation $U$. In other words, there exists some rotation transformation $U$ and some scaling transformation $S$ such that $U(S(X)) = Y$.

**Proof of the "Cube" Part:**

Recall that
$$V(X) = \int_{X} dV = \iiint_X dx dy dz$$
and performing the change of variables
$$\vec{r} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\  y \\ z\end{bmatrix} \to U \cdot S \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\  y \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x' \\  y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \vec{r}~'$$
the integral from above becomes
$$V(X) = \iiint_X dx dy dz = \iiint_{U(S(X))} \left|\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial U(S(\vec{r}))}\right| dx' dy' dz' = \iiint_{Y} \left|U S \right|^{-1} dx' dy' dz'$$
But $|US| = |U|\cdot |S| = |S| = k^3$ as the determinant of any rotation matrix is one. Thus, we have
$$V(X) = \iiint_X dx dy dz = k^{-3} \iiint_{Y} dx' dy' dz' = \frac{V(Y)}{k^3} \iff V(Y) = k^3 \cdot V(X)$$

**Proof of the "Square" Part:**

As for the surface area, note that
$$A(X) = \iint_{\partial X} dA = \iint_{T} \left\|\frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t}\right\| ds dt$$
where $\vec{x}: (s, t) \to (x, y, z)$ is parameterization of the surface of $X$ and $T$ is the appropriate region over which $(s, t)$ varies. Consider a similar parameterization $\vec{x}' : (s, t) \to U(S(x, y, z))$ where $(s, t)$ again varies in the region $T$. Clearly, this parameterization traces out the surface $Y$, namely
$$A(Y) = \iint_{T} \left\|\frac{\partial \vec{x}'(s, t)}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \vec{x}'(s, t)}{\partial t}\right\| ds dt$$
As $U$ and $S$ are just constant linear transforms, we may take them out of the derivative:
$$\iint_{T} \left\|\frac{\partial \vec{x}'(s, t)}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \vec{x}'(s, t)}{\partial t}\right\| ds dt = \iint_{T} \left\|U\left(S\left(\frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial s}\right)\right) \times U\left(S\left(\frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t}\right)\right) \right\| ds dt $$
Recalling that all orthogonal transforms preserve lengths and angles and thus the magnitude of the cross-product, it follows that we can just ignore $U$ in the above expression. Additionally, $S$ merely scales its argument by $k$, so ultimately we have
\begin{align*}
\iint_{T} \left\|U\left(S\left(\frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial s}\right)\right) \times U\left(S\left(\frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t}\right)\right) \right\| ds dt = \iint_{T} \left\|k \frac{\partial \vec{x}'(s, t)}{\partial s} \times  k \frac{\partial \vec{x}'(s, t)}{\partial t}\right\| ds dt \\ \\
= k^2 \iint_{T} \left\|\frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t}\right\| ds dt = k^2 A(X)
\end{align*}
as desired. $\square$